# Is there a discrete signal which isn't discrete in time?

Tags: real-time

Is there a *discrete signal* which isn't discrete in time (rather, discrete in at least one other thing which isn't time)?

If so please share a typical example.

Comment: Well, *technically*...

Comment: As far as I am aware, when someone refers to a signal being discrete, it means that it has been discretised in time. This means that there can't be a discrete signal which is not discrete in its temporal variable. Of course, this is based on this definition...

Comment: Sure. Every signal that's periodic in time is discrete in frequency.

Comment: @Hilmar periodic in time = discrete in frequency. Hmm a nice way to put it. It appears often, and hence **not continuously frequent**. Okay, I think I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Any signal that repeats in time will be discrete in frequency (meaning have non-zero values only at discrete intervals). The time domain waveform can be continuous or discrete which is independent of its Fourier Transform of being continuous or discrete. I expand on this with examples at this similar post [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82112/is-discrete-or-continuous-a-matter-of-frequency/82113#82113).

Reaching here, but we could consider antenna arrays as an example using signals with a source that is discrete in space.